# mysql bitwise AND on value longer than 64bits

Tags: mysql

I have table:

```
+----------------+--------------+
| name (varchar) | flags (text) |
+----------------+--------------+
| A              | 100001000000 |
| B              | 100001000000 |
| C              | 000001000000 |
| D              | 000001000000 |
+----------------+--------------+
```

`Flags` stores binary values **longer than 64 bits** as TEXT.

I want to do:

```
SELECT name, conv(flags, 2, 2) & conv('100000000001', 2, 2) FROM users;
```

Which should return:

```
+----------------+--------------+
| name (varchar) | flags (text) |
+----------------+--------------+
| A              | 1            |
| B              | 1            |
| C              | 0            |
| D              | 0            |
+----------------+--------------+
```

But when `flag > 2^64-1` I get always `1` because `conv` always returns `2^64-1`

How can I work this around?

Comment: I think there would be an even better solution not to use a bitmask with more than 64 values. But maybe a solution for you is, to split the bitmask in smaller chunks, either by strsplitting the text or by using a second column in the database.

Comment: Since you are emulating binary data with text, I have the impression that you'll also have to emulate binary operators with string manipulation functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cant. CPUs works in 32/64 bits mode. & is a high level operator that will be converted to an low level assembly "AND" (CPU instruction)

So bitwise operators like & ~ << >> .... are always limited to 32/64 bits.
In MySQL bitwise operators are limited to 64 bits, a VM (Virtual machine) in MySQL will make the conversion so bitwise operators also can run on 32 bit system but it should be slower vs 64 bit systems because more instructions are needed.

**If you want to handle flags do it in your application but wait same problem there so rethink your idea and structure.**

Answer (score -1):

[this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/dealing-with-very-large-bitmasks.aspx) may be of some help... i haven't particularly read through the whole thing in detail, but the idea is this:

create a table of numbers that represent all of your possible masked values.
store your mask as a string, and compare it to your number table substrings at a time.

this probably isn't a very good explanation, so i encourage you to read the link. 
[here](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) is some more about using number tables from the same author.